# Enviar notificaciones con topic en Huawei

Tags: rest, curl, push-notification, huawei-mobile-services

Tengo un problema con El Push Kit de Huawei. Cuando trato de mandar una notificación a un topic me manda un error 500

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://push-api.cloud.huawei.com/v1/{my_app_id}/messages:send' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer my_token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8' \
--data-raw '{
  "validate_only": false,
  "message": {
    "topic": "semple-topic",
    "data": "some-data"
  }
}'
```

Este es el response que me manda

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>504 Gateway Time-out</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1>
    </center>
    <hr>
    <center>openresty</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Alguien sabe como resolverlo?

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema se resuelve cambiando la petición de GET a POST

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://push-api.cloud.huawei.com/v1/{my_app_id}/messages:send' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer my_token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8' \
--data-raw '{
  "validate_only": false,
  "message": {
    "topic": "semple-topic",
    "data": "some-data"
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Mensaje de error 504, que significa Error de red. Verifique lo siguiente:

1. Check the network.
2. Ping our domain name.
3. Replace my_app_id in the address with the actual app ID.